# iOS App leaking

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am having a Navigation based app with a few buttons on the first View (not using ARC). By touching one button `optionPressed` gets triggered to push to another View.

When I analyse the code for leaks. I get the following warning. "Potential leak of an object" `[self.displayViewController setCurrentPhoto:sender.currentTitle];`

How should I release the self.displayViewController and where if that's the cause.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DisplayViewController.h"

@class DisplayViewController;

@interface Pocket_DjangoViewController : UIViewController 


- (IBAction)optionPressed:(UIButton *)sender;

@property (retain, nonatomic) DisplayViewController *displayViewController;


@end
```

.m

```
- (IBAction)optionPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{

    if (!self.displayViewController) {
        self.displayViewController = [[DisplayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DisplayViewController" bundle:nil];
    }

    [self.displayViewController setCurrentPhoto:sender.currentTitle];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.displayViewController animated:YES];

    //[self.displayViewController release];
    //self.displayViewController = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leak stems for this line:

```
self.displayViewController = [[DisplayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DisplayViewController" bundle:nil];
```

you should have:

```
self.displayViewController = [[[DisplayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DisplayViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

In your actual code, you are creating an object:

```
[[DisplayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DisplayViewController" bundle:nil];
```

which is already retained; then you assign it to a retain property:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) DisplayViewController *displayViewController;
```

and this will create a retain unbalance, as the original alloc is never released and only the retain called by the property is eventually released.

Comment: Good this solved my problem!! I found that my app consumes: 2.80, 3 Live MB ; 10,3 Living; 31 Overall.  Is this ok for users run my simple app smoothly?